# Adding Flask support to an existing Pycharm project

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

I'm working on a small project where it would be helpful to display trivial web pages. It's being developed in PyCharm, the pro edition.

This is an existing project, so it wasn't created as a Flask app to begin with.

I've added Flask to my requirements.txt and ensured that its installed. However, I don't get autocompletion of any Jinja templates - essentially, the HTML file I created is treated like dumb HTML.

How do I get PyCharm to recognize that I'm using Flask and to act accordingly?

[image: IDE Screenshot]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to tell PyCharm which folders contain your templates.

1. Go to `Settings/Project: NAME/Project Structure`
2. Click on the folder containing your templates and click the purple `Templates` button.

It will probably warn you that no template language is specified. If that is the case

3. go to `Settings/Language & Frameworks/Python Template Languages`
4. In the combobox `Template Language:` select your template language (jinja?)
5. Under `Template file types` select the file type (probably HTML)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a project ( File->New Project ) to choose:

[image]

After the creation of the project to select the appropriate file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new Flask Project will just set the python template language as `Jinja2` and give you a skeleton (a web server which respond 'Hello World' to client).

Therefore, if you have a existing project, press `Prefences` -> Search `Python Template Languages` -> and now you can change it to `Jinja2`